# What do you call a complex number that is not in polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers

A complex number is usually written as $Z_1 = a + b \cdot i$.

A complex number in polar form is something like $Z_2 = r (\cos(\phi) + \sin(\phi) \cdot i)$ which can alternatively be written as $Z_2 = r\cdot e^{i \cdot \phi}$.

When the term 'complex number' is used, this encompasses both kinds of notations.

What is the name of the 'normal' complex number representation that is *not* in polar form?

Comment: I've usually heard "Cartesian" or "co-ordinate" form when referring to complex numbers in the form $z = \Re(z) + i\Im(z)$.

Comment: Rectangular form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard both of the expressions rectangular form and cartesian form used (*I* use them both). Coordinate form is a bit misleading because polar coordinates are also coordinates, but it wouldn't surprise me if it was used by some.